# Row position wrongly changing background color in Recyclerview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview. I am Passing List for Recyclerview item.In that List I have one int variable name **"isAlready"**  if that int==1, i am changing background color.but item position is changing while scrolling so that it changing background color for wrong item.i know recyclerview will 
reuse the item.so please give a solution.
Here is my code.

```
    public class ListOfUserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListOfUserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<ListOfUserPojo> listOfUserPojs;

private CallBackRequest mCallBack;


public ListOfUserAdapter(Context context,List<ListOfUserPojo> listOfUserPojs,CallBackRequest callBackRequest) {
    this.context=context;
   this.listOfUserPojs=listOfUserPojs;
    mCallBack=callBackRequest;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)   {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_class, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     holder.textView.setText(listOfUserPojs.get(position).getProfile().getFullname());
   Log.d("size ",""+listOfUserPojs.size());
    // declare the builder object once.
    TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder()
            .beginConfig()
            .endConfig()
            .round();

    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT

    // reuse the builder specs to create multiple drawables
    TextDrawable textDrawable = builder.build(listOfUserPojs.get(position).getProfile().getFullname().substring(0,1), generator.getRandomColor());

    holder.imgUser.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
    Log.d("boolean ",""+listOfUserPojs.get(position).getUserId());
    if (listOfUserPojs.get(position).isAlready()==1){
        holder.card_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    holder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              if (listOfUserPojs.get(position).isAlready()!=1){
                  showDialog(listOfUserPojs.get(position).getProfile().getFullname(),Integer.valueOf(listOfUserPojs.get(position).getUserId()));
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "You have shown Interest already", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

          }
      });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  listOfUserPojs.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.textUserName)
    TextView textView;


    @BindView(R.id.card_view)
    LinearLayout card_view;

    @BindView(R.id.img_user)
    ImageView imgUser;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }
}


private void showDialog(final String name, final Integer userId) {

    // creating the fullscreen dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.audio_dialog);

    if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {

        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =    R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button btn_yes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    Button btn_no = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    TextView name_=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

    name_.setText(name);

    btn_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           mCallBack.sendRequestCall();
            Intent intent =new Intent(context,ConnectingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userid",userId);
            intent.putExtra("name",name);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });



    btn_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();


        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

public interface CallBackRequest{
    void sendRequestCall();

}
}
```

ListofuserPojo:

```
    public class ListOfUserPojo {


@JsonProperty("profile")
private Profile profile;

@JsonProperty("userId")
private String userId;

public Profile getProfile ()
{
    return profile;
}

public void setProfile (Profile profile)
{
    this.profile = profile;
}

public String getUserId ()
{
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId (String userId)
{
    this.userId = userId;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [profile = "+profile+", userId = "+userId+"]";
}

public class Profile
{
    @JsonProperty("fullname")
    private String fullname;

    public String getFullname ()
    {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname (String fullname)
    {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [fullname = "+fullname+"]";
    }
}
@JsonIgnore
private int isAlready ;

public int isAlready() {
    return isAlready;
}

public void setAlready(int already) {
    isAlready = already;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In that List I have one int variable name "isAlready" if that int==1,
>   i am changing background color.but item position is changing while
>   scrolling so that it changing background color for wrong item.i know
>   recyclerview will reuse the item.so please give a solution. Here is my
>   code.

As you correctly stated that's the recycling mechanism of the `RecyclerView`'s cells. In order to fix it you will have to simply 'reset' the background color if the condition is false. EG

```
 if (listOfUserPojs.get(position).isAlready()==1){
      holder.card_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
 } else {
      holder.card_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR)
 }
```

to improve readability you could think about create a method in your `ViewHolder` that updates the `UI`, and call it from `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (listOfUserPojs.get(position).isAlready()==1){
    holder.card_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}else holder.card_view.setBackgroundColor(0);
}
```